# Cannot change the compression level for BZIP2 with Tar

Tags: linux, compression, tar, bzip2, bzip

I need to change the compression level for BZIP2 compression with tar. I found that we can set the compression level and run the tar command to compress. I tried different compression levels using the following command, but it seems like `BZIP2=-<compression level>` does not change the compression level.

```
BZIP2=-1
tar -cjvf <output_file> <input_file>
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: `tar -cv input | bzip2 -c -1 > output.tar.bz2`

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this "linux", I will assume that you are using GNU tar. Then you can give the compression command with options using `-I`:

```
tar -I="bzip2 -1" -cvf out.tar.bz2 files
```